# Interpreting dataframe out of Array JSON in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am having a column of below json string in my dataframe how can I explode/flatten it to get single level dataframe ?
Currently the schema is

```
df
|-json_data (StringType)
```

how can I have a df of below schema ?

```
df
|-key1
|-key2_signal
|-key2_value
```

---

```
[{
    "key1": 1647336730000,
    "key2": [
      {
        "signal": "signal_key_1",
        "value": 73.6
    },
      {
        "signal": "signal_key_2",
        "value": 3.375
    },
      {
        "signal": "signal_key_3",
        "value": 13.82
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's how you should do it.

Explanation:

1. Creating the dummy for practice on your sample data. (df1 creation)
2. Take the string column and cast it to be an actual JSON.
3. Select all of the fields.
4. Explode key2 since it's a list.
5. select all the relevant keys from within key2
6. select key1 and key2 related data. using asterisk (*)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [{'json_data': [json.dumps({
        "key1": 1647336730000,
        "key2": [
            {
                "signal": "signal_key_1",
                "value": 73.6
            },
            {
                "signal": "signal_key_2",
                "value": 3.375
            },
            {
                "signal": "signal_key_3",
                "value": 13.82
            }]
    })]}],
    schema=StructType([StructField('json_data', StringType(), True)])
)
(
    df1
    .withColumn('actual', f.from_json(f.col('json_data'), f.schema_of_json(f.lit(df1.select(f.col("json_data")).first()[0]))))
    .withColumn('data', f.explode('actual'))
    .drop('actual')
    .withColumn('key2', f.explode('data.key2'))
    .drop('json_data')
    .select('data.key1', 'key2.*').show()
    )
# +-------------+------------+-----+
# |         key1|      signal|value|
# +-------------+------------+-----+
# |1647336730000|signal_key_1| 73.6|
# |1647336730000|signal_key_2|3.375|
# |1647336730000|signal_key_3|13.82|
# +-------------+------------+-----+
```

Comment: Benny Elgazar the json which you have taken is bit different than the one I provided in the question. The json has square brackets outside. i.e. the json.dumps statement has something like this json.dumps(  [ {...} ] ).

Comment: I just tried to mimic the data frame you already have.
Can you add show the printSchema of your current dataframe?

Comment: It is almost same but it has list box brackets outside the dictionary object
I have created the dataframe from the code you provided and added the box bracket.


|json_data                  |                                                                                                                                           


|[{"key1": 1647336730000, "key2": [{"signal": "signal_key_1", "value": 73.6}, {"signal": "signal_key_2", "value": 3.375}, {"signal": "signal_key_3", "value": 13.82}]}]|

Comment: so its just another explode before, I'll adjust it for you

Comment: @Tizen I modified my solution to fit your request.